# Check two tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following function:

```
function login_check($email, $password)
{
    $email       = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password    = md5($password);
    $login_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `count`, `id` FROM `table_name` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `password`='$password'");  

    return (mysql_result($login_query, 0) == 1) ? mysql_result($login_query, 0, 'id') : mysql_error();
}
```

I want it to check if the user login is correct in two different tables not only one since I've made another table for users who have authenticated their twitter account with my site.

Comment: Should the password and email be the same in both tables? I see in your example you're using only one table, one email and one password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off with a single table that has an "authenticated with Twitter" flag but you can check both with something like this:

```
select exists(
    select 1 from table_name where email = '$email' and password = '$password'
    union
    select 1 from twitter_table where email = '$email' and password = '$password'
)
```

MySQL will give you a one (AKA true) if at least one of the tables has what you're looking for and a zero (AKA false) if neither has a match.

Using the `select exists(select 1...)` trick will also be faster than counting as the database only needs to find one match or check the indexes to know that there are no matches before it returns from the query.

Comment: True. Having one table would be better,but each table has different rows. how can I put them both in one table ?
Thanks.

Comment: @wadie: What does the other table look like?

Comment: The one with the oauth rows is Twitter's table.
http://imgit.me/i/5h4m4V5.png

http://imgit.me/i/4K5w6U8.png
Do you think I can just add the two extra rows to the first table ?

Comment: Everyone should have an entry in your users table then the OAuth table would have a user_id that points at your users table. So if someone is logging in through OAuth then you look at the OAuth table end follow the link to the users table; if they logging in directly then you check the users table. You should know which login mechanism they're using, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an union view of both tables:

```
CREATE VIEW combined_accounts AS
  (SELECT id, twitter_mail AS mail, password FROM twitter_accounts)
  UNION
  (SELECT id, mail, password FROM my_accounts);
```